# IntelliJ IDEA jumps in project structure to folder where the file is located

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

IntelliJ IDEA jumps in project structure to folder where the file is located when I open it.

How to stop this? I don't want to see how project structures always jumping.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#scroll_to_from_source?

Answer (score 3):

1. Use Find Action. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> On MacOS. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on Windows/Linux.
2. Search for "Always Select Opened File"
3. Make sure it is off [image: Find Action popup]